# Scrape <frameset> contents using cURL

Tags: curl, frameset

How can I use cURL to scrape from a page that hides the data I'm really interested in inside one of the frames of a `<frameset>`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, when I need to scrape things that are a little more complicated I'm a huge fan of Perl and the module WWW::Mechanize http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm

There are examples on the module page, but if you do a google search for 'Screen scraping with perl', you will find all kinds of examples.  It can manage cookies for you as well.

NOTE:  I'm sure this can all be accomplished with multiple curl request and some grep'ing -- but my experience has been primarily with Perl.

Comment: Yeh it's populating the frameset through javascript.So what should I do to Scrap,any suggestion is greatly appreciated.
The URL from which I want to scrap is :"http://groceries.asda.com/asda-estore/catalog/sectionpagecontainer.jsp?departmentid=1214921923758"